# DiagrammeR and R Markdown pdf: Remove space around diagram?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown, diagrammer

I've had quite some problems working with the package DiagrammeR in R Markdown with pdf specified as output. I managed to display the diagram but as you will se in the following, there is quite a lot of space around the diagram.

Have a look at my sample code here:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "test"
date: "14/05/2020"
output: pdf_document
---

# My Markdown-file
This is my RMarkdown-file. Now I want to add a flowchart using the packages DiagrammeR. 

```{r figure_1, echo = FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.cap = "Flowchart 1: Some explanation"}

DiagrammeR::grViz(" 
      digraph test {

        node [shape = circle] 
          A; B

        A -> B

      }
        ")

```

I now continue writing.
````

This code produces the following output:

[image]

Notice the following:

1. The diagram is not centered even though I have specified it to be so in the code-chunk.
2. There is a huge gap between the diagram and the caption.

How do I fix these issues? I love the packages but it might be too hard to work with when output is pdf? Maybe other packages are better?

Comment: Maybe look at the **gmisc** package as an alternative?

Comment: On non-Windows systems, PDF figures are cropped by default, if the `pdfcrop` utility is present.  See `?rmarkdown::pdf_document` argument `fig_crop`. If you are not on Windows, make sure `pdfcrop` is on your path.  If you are on Windows, things are harder:  `knitr` won't even try to run it.  Sorry, I'm not on Windows, so can't give you detailed instructions on how to get around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. I played a little bit around with the [markdown chunk options](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/) and found the following workaround to embed a png instead of a pdf figure:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "test"
date: "14/05/2020"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
---

# My Markdown-file

This is my RMarkdown-file. Now I want to add a flowchart using the packages DiagrammeR.

```{r echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Flowchart 1: Some explanation", dev='png'}
library("DiagrammeR")
grViz("
      digraph test {
        node [shape = circle]
        A, B

        A -> B
      }
 ")
```

I now continue writing.
````

Other devices like `Cairo_PDF` worked also, but not as expected and just produced a png. I left the `keep_tex` option in to ease debugging.